# mvc inconsistent accessibility property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to all this but I could not find the answer. (i'm sorry for my noobyness)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Myproject.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public List<Options> **Options** { get; set; }
        public List<Variants> **Variants** { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(I have started the bit that has blue underlines)

I have two other models an options.cs model and a variants.cs model.

The thing is that I get this error message on the options and variants text after the list.
I have been following the MVC 02 | Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Models tutorial and when making the model Chris uses `public List<Sessions> Sessions { get; set; }` and he does not get any blue underlines...

My question is why am i getting "inconsistent accessibility property"

Chris is using 2012 and I'm using 2013 visual studios. So it has something to do with that but why? and how do i fix it?

I'm getting the same error on my DbSet Options { get; set; } and my Variants DbsSet

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the options.cs and variants.cs files mark your classes as **public**:

```
public class Options { ... } 
public class Variants { ... }
```

In public class you can't expose public property of type which is not public, because in this scenario the other external assemblies can view you public property but if the class is not public this type is unknown for them.